# iOS add Day View Calendar in application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, calendar

I am trying to make an application with a `day-view-calendar` in it. I know there are quite a few questions that implicit the same as mine, but I haven't found an answer that makes it clear for me. 
I want to make a `day-view-calendar` which contains several (5 or 6) columns. So that you can add items for 5 or 6 different users in one view.

Furthermore I want to have the lay-out similar to the `iPhone calendar day view.`

I am totally new here, can someone please help me how to solve my "issue"?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use tapku calendar library to get the same view.

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Check this it may help you

Comment: Thank you Divz for your quick answer!

Comment: @Jan.PetersNL your welcome have you check this is it help you?

Comment: Still I'm wondering if its possible to have multiple columns in a day-view calendar. So that the user can add apppointments on one day for different persons

Comment: @Jan.PetersNL ye you can detect the click event when ever you select the date and you can add the appointments for the day.

Comment: ok then, well I have to figure it out (complete new for me), but thanks. Now I know it will be possible

Comment: Link is not Opening.

Comment: they have removed this i Will update this answer again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use anyone of these

1. https://github.com/Clancey/UICalendar
2. https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar
3. https://github.com/vgrichina/ios-calendar
4. https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar

Comment: Still I'm wondering if its possible to have multiple columns in a day-view calendar. So that the user can add apppointments on one day for different persons.

Comment: Not all of this provide a day view as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout i created day view using Tapku library [DayView](https://github.com/safecase123/Calender)

I have customized to some extent just like `iCalender`

Comment: Tapku day view has a major bug. On selecting a date other than current date, no events are displayed. And no solution has been shared till now which works.